# Is there anyway to make TCP socket keep alive when switching to other App?

Tags: sockets, windows-phone-8.1

I'm trying to make TCP socket keep alive in Windows Phone 8.1 using WinRT. But it don't seem no way to accomplished. I read the documents on MSDN ([this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/jj662741.aspx)) it say `ControlChannelTrigger` isn't supported on Windows Phone.

I'm sure there is a way to do this since Remote Desktop by Microsoft can be switched to other App and connection is still alive.

Thanks for advance.

Answer (score 0):

> TCP socket keep alive ... can be switched to other App and connection is still alive

I think you mix up concepts.
TCP socket keep alive is only to detect loss of connectivity to the peer.
What you see with Remote Desktop is that it maintains its own state over multiple TCP connections. But this kind of resuming has to be implemented by the application itself and in a application specific way.